# How to change component order by screen size in React & TailwindCSS

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, tailwind-css

I am using React with Tailwind CSS and want to conditionally render/reorder components.
Let say we want to show this order when mobile size

```
<div1 />
<div2 />
<div3 />
```

but desktop size

```
<div3 />
<div1 />
<div2 />
```

In tailwind css we can specify screen size border like `sm (minWidth:375px)`, `md (minWidth:415px)`, `lg (minWidth:1200px)` then apply css styling but how can we use this screen size for React component itself rendering condition?

Comment: you can try doing `<div><div1 class="lg:hidden"/><div3 class="hidden lg:block"/><div>`  It is a kind of conditional rendering

Comment: It doesn't work with an arbitrary reordering like your example, but some cases might be satisfied by using `flex-col-reverse` or `flex-row-reverse`. For example: `sm:flex sm:flex-col-reverse`. See: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-direction#column-reversed

Answer (score 1):

I think [checking this documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/order#ordering-flex-and-grid-items) for the order of the items could be helpful. You could try doing something like:

```
<div className="flex flex-col">
 <div className="lg:order-last">01</div>
 <div>02</div>
 <div>03</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Grid is pretty useful for creating more complex logic that is also easy to manage. Consider the following, which has 3 different orders defined:

```html
<div class="grid grid-rows-3">
  <div class="md:row-start-2">1</div>
  <div class="lg:row-start-1">2</div>
  <div class="md:row-start-1 lg:row-start-auto">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

##### Use the tailwind's [order](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/order) class

```
<div class="flex justify-between">
  <div class="h-40 w-60 bg-blue-600 text-center text-8xl">Div 1</div>
  <div class="h-40 w-60 bg-blue-600 text-center text-8xl">Div 2</div>
  <div class="h-40 w-60 bg-blue-600 text-center text-8xl lg:order-first">Div 3</div>
</div>
```

Output in small screen:

[image]

Output in large screen:

[image]

##### Code link : [tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/k6ONOx3lRt)